# maven-pax-provision + equinox: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Tags: maven, osgi, equinox, apache-felix, pax-runner

i am experiencing some strang, non reproducible, behavior.

I am developing an OSGi Application using the maven-bundle-plugin and the maven-pax-plugin to run it in Apache Felix and Eclipse Equinox.

Since today i sometimes get the following error when i try to start or stop a bundle e.g.

lb works fine

Output (excerpt):

```
0|Active     |    0|OSGi System Bundle (3.8.1.v20120830-144521)
1|Active     |    1|Console plug-in (1.0.0.v20120522-1841)
2|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Command (0.12.0)
3|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Runtime (0.10.0)
4|Active     |    1|Apache Felix Gogo Shell (0.10.0)
5|Active     |    5|OSGi R4 Core Bundle (4.1.0)
6|Active     |    5|slf4j-api (1.6.6)
7|Active     |    5|Logback Core Module (1.0.7)
8|Active     |    5|Logback Classic Module (1.0.7)
```

but when i try stop 6 for example i get the following exception:

```
g! stop 6
java.lang.ClassCastException: java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.String
at org.eclipse.equinox.console.commands.EquinoxCommandsConverter.convert(EquinoxCommandsConverter.java:61)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProcessorImpl.convert(CommandProcessorImpl.java:254)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.convert(CommandSessionImpl.java:374)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.coerce(Reflective.java:389)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.coerce(Reflective.java:310)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:110)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Console.run(Console.java:62)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.console(Shell.java:203)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Shell.gosh(Shell.java:128)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Reflective.invoke(Reflective.java:137)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandProxy.execute(CommandProxy.java:82)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeCmd(Closure.java:477)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.executeStatement(Closure.java:403)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Pipe.run(Pipe.java:108)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:183)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.Closure.execute(Closure.java:120)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime.CommandSessionImpl.execute(CommandSessionImpl.java:89)
at org.apache.felix.gogo.shell.Activator.run(Activator.java:75)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

This happens with every Bundle
Everything works fine in Felix tough.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's an error inside equinox commands bundle. It cannot convert type correctly. gogo runtime prints printStackTrace and executes the command correctly with felix commands.